How to understand transpose operation on a 3D or Higher Dimensional Array
Consider a 3D array array_3d with shape (3, 2, 2):
array_3d = np.array([
    [[ 0,  1],
     [ 2,  3]],

    [[ 4,  5],
     [ 6,  7]],

    [[ 8,  9],
     [10, 11]]
])

array_3d.shape = (3, 2, 2)

Transposed Array
transposed_3d = np.transpose(array_3d)

transposed_3d.shape = (2, 2, 3)

transposed_3d = [
    [[ 0,  4,  8],
     [ 2,  6, 10]],

    [[ 1,  5,  9],
     [ 3,  7, 11]]
]

In case of 2D array it's easy to identify that rows become columns and Columns become rows.
But in case of 3D or higher dimension there is no direct notion of rows and columns. So, how can one predict which element of the original array_3d will be mapped on transposed_3d array?
We can try to make sense of how elements are mapped by looking at the indices explicitly but it's too cumbersome and messy.One way that helps me most is by thinking in terms of strides and how it changes during transpose.
Could anyone suggest any other mental model to grasp the transpose notion in higher dimensional ndarray?

The axes are reversed. If you transposed a shape (2, 3, 4, 5) array, you receive a shape (5, 4, 3, 2) array. So A[i, j, k, ...] == np.transpose(A)[..., k, j, i], if that makes sense

All the change info is in the shape and strides  It is hard to visualize or describe in therms of rows/colunns

Just look at how the numbers 0,1,2,3,4.... are aranged in the two displays.  In one 0-1 is across the columns of one row, in the other, they jump from one block to the next (that's the first size 2 dimension).  It may be hard to describe in words, but should be clear if described abstractly by dimension.

Read the docs, please. All the info you need is there.

The short and correct answer has already been given in @Chrysophylaxs's comment:
When transposing an n-D array, as is written in the Numpy documentation, the order of axes is reversed (quote, For an n-D array, … if axes are not provided, then transpose(a).shape == a.shape[::-1]); so, for example, a 2×3×4-shaped 3-D array becomes 4×3×2-shaped. This, if you think of it, can be seen as a meaningful generalization of the 2-D case.
As to a mental model, here are some thoughts on visual mental models for the 2-D and 3-D case, and some more general thoughts on the n-D case:
2-D case
To be clear about the visual mental model in the 2-D case that probably most Numpy users share, I will briefly summarize it in words:
We can think of a 2-D Numpy array as a rectangle, which, if we look at the printout of such an array, is oriented as follows:

Axis 0 increases with the rows – we could think of this as the height axis of our rectangle.
Axis 1 increases with the columns – we could think of this as the width axis of our rectangle.

If we apply the transpose, then the axes get swapped, i.e. axis 0 becomes axis 1 and vice versa. If we pick up the mental model of our rectangle from above, this means:

(axis 0 → axis 1): What was on top is now on the left, what was at the bottom is now on the right.
(axis 1 → axis 0): What was on the left is now on top, what was on the right is now at the bottom.

Maybe we should also keep in mind what this is not: Namely, this is not the same as a rotation by 90 degrees (which would require an additional reversal of the values along one axis) – this, arguably, makes visualizing even the 2-D case not quite intuitive.
3-D case
We can probably still gain a visual mental model for the 3-D case if we think of our array as a cuboid, but it may get harder for more dimensions (at least personally, I cannot really visualize objects in more than 3 dimensions, let alone transformations on them). If we look at the printout of the 3-D Numpy array and its transpose from your question, we can see the following:

Axis 0 is shown as a stack of 2-D slices – we could think of this as the depth axis of our cuboid, e.g. with the first slice in the back and the last slice in front.
Axis 1 increases with the rows in each slice, axis 2 increases with the columns in each slice (just as axes 0 and 1 in the 2-D case) – we could think of these as the height and width axes of our cuboid.

If we apply the transpose, then, as already mentioned, the order of axes gets reversed. In the 3-D case, this means:

Axis 0 becomes axis 2,
axis 2 becomes axis 0,
axis 1 stays in place.

If we pick up the mental model of our cuboid from above, this means:

(axis 0 → axis 2): What was in the back is now on the left, what was in front is now on the right.
(axis 2 → axis 0): What was on the left is now in the back, what was on the right is now in front.
(axis 1 → axis 1): What was on top stays on top, what was at the bottom stays at the bottom.

In other words, we can visualize the 3-D transpose by looking onto our array cuboid from the top (so, along axis 1) and then see the top surface (and with it, all parallel slices below it) getting transposed just as in the 2-D case, with the top-to-bottom order of slices remaining intact.
We can verify this by tracing some ranges of values in the array from your question:

(axis 0 → axis 2): Values [0, 4, 8], which progress back-to-front in the given array, progress left-to-right in its transpose.
(axis 2 → axis 0): Values [0, 1], which progress left-to-right in the given array, progress back-to-front in its transpose.
(axis 1 → axis 1): Values [0, 2], which progress top-to-bottom in the given array, still progress top-to-bottom in its transpose.

n-D case
For the n-D case, as already mentioned and as basically also already answered by the comments of @Chrysophylaxs and @hpaulj, it is probably pointless to try and visualize array shapes and array transformations. However, what probably matters most in any case is: Where do I find specific values before and after transforming an array in some way?
With the transpose as defined by Numpy for the n-D case, this is pretty straightforward: What was at index a[i,j,k,l,…] before transposing is at index a.T[…,l,k,j,i] after transposing. In other words: the values of indices remain the same, only their order is reversed.
